# Как создать архив в памяти и отправить его?

Tags: python

Мне требуется собрать архив в памяти и отправить его, я нашёл примерный код, но он опятьже сохраняет архив на диск, без сохранения не придумал как его отправить возможно.

```
import io, zipfile

zip_buffer = io.BytesIO()
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buffer, "a", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, False) as zip_file:
    for file_name, data in [('1.txt', io.BytesIO(b'111')), ('2.txt', io.BytesIO(b'222'))]:
        zip_file.writestr(file_name, data.getvalue())
with open(r'Путь', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(zip_buffer.getvalue())
```

Comment: Ну вот вы бинарное содержимое архива получаете через `zip_buffer.getvalue()`, вот и отправляйте полученное куда хотите.

Comment: ну в плане, как я могу отправить этот бинарный код? без сохранения
open(zip_buffer.getvalue(), 'rb')

Comment: А куда и через что вы хотите отправить zip файл?

Comment: Это бинарные данные с содержимым архива, они у вас считайте в переменной питона лежат. Хотите их в файл пишите (как в вашем коде), хотите к почте прикладывайте (но тогда и вопрос надо задавать соответствующий - как приложить бинарные данные к письму), хотите через `http post request` отправляйте, да что угодно.

Comment: я разобрался thanks